# Apache Sqoop import error

Tags: hadoop, import, cloudera, sqoop, cloudera-cdh

I am getting the following error while trying to import table from MySql to HDFS. I am using cloudera CDH 4 VM.

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase\
> --user root\
> --password aaaaaaaa\
> --table bike
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
14/12/08 11:44:40 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.3-cdh4.7.0
14/12/08 11:44:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
14/12/08 11:44:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: root--password
14/12/08 11:44:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: aaaaaaaa--table
14/12/08 11:44:41 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: bike

Try --help for usage instructions.
usage: sqoop import [GENERIC-ARGS] [TOOL-ARGS]
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://mysql_server:3306/mydatabase --username root --password aaaaaaaa --table bike ;
```

you shoud use **--username** instead of --user